# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'operationKind') - Recoil-Relay graphQLSelector

Tags: typescript, relayjs, recoiljs

I am using `recoil-relay` to fetch queries directly for selectors.
Currently, I am using `graphQLSelector`, but having problems when trying to get the value returned by the selector.
Sample code:

```
import { graphql } from "react-relay";
import { graphQLSelector } from "recoil-relay";
import { RelayEnvironment } from "../relay_env";

export interface Client {
  Id: string;
  age: string;
  gender: string;
  income: string;
  location: string;
}

const clientsSelector = graphQLSelector({
  key: "clientsSelector",
  environment: RelayEnvironment,
  query: graphql`
    query ClientsAtomsQuery {
      clients {
        Id
        age
        gender
        income
        location
      }
    }
  `,
  variables: {},
  mapResponse: (data) => data.clients as Array<Client>,
});
```

The error appears in runtime, while executing:

```
const clients = useRecoilValue(clientsSelector);
```

The relay environment is not the problem, because when I try to use the same query using only Relay, it works.

The relay-compiler is working and generates the correct `.graphql.ts` file:

```
...

import { ConcreteRequest, Query } from 'relay-runtime';
export type ClientsAtomsQuery$variables = {};
export type ClientsAtomsQuery$data = {
  readonly clients: ReadonlyArray<{
    readonly Id: number | null;
    readonly age: string;
    readonly gender: string;
    readonly income: string;
    readonly location: string;
  }>;
};
export type ClientsAtomsQuery = {
  response: ClientsAtomsQuery$data;
  variables: ClientsAtomsQuery$variables;
};

const node: ConcreteRequest = (function(){
var v0 = [
  {
    "alias": null,
    "args": null,
    "concreteType": "Client",
    "kind": "LinkedField",
    "name": "clients",
    "plural": true,
    "selections": [
      {
        "alias": null,
        "args": null,
        "kind": "ScalarField",
        "name": "Id",
        "storageKey": null
      },
      {
        "alias": null,
        "args": null,
        "kind": "ScalarField",
        "name": "age",
        "storageKey": null
      },
      {
        "alias": null,
        "args": null,
        "kind": "ScalarField",
        "name": "gender",
        "storageKey": null
      },
      {
        "alias": null,
        "args": null,
        "kind": "ScalarField",
        "name": "income",
        "storageKey": null
      },
      {
        "alias": null,
        "args": null,
        "kind": "ScalarField",
        "name": "location",
        "storageKey": null
      }
    ],
    "storageKey": null
  }
];
return {
  "fragment": {
    "argumentDefinitions": [],
    "kind": "Fragment",
    "metadata": null,
    "name": "ClientsAtomsQuery",
    "selections": (v0/*: any*/),
    "type": "Query",
    "abstractKey": null
  },
  "kind": "Request",
  "operation": {
    "argumentDefinitions": [],
    "kind": "Operation",
    "name": "ClientsAtomsQuery",
    "selections": (v0/*: any*/)
  },
  "params": {
    "cacheID": "30edf9a9b7f2c445a8a07730198d719d",
    "id": null,
    "metadata": {},
    "name": "ClientsAtomsQuery",
    "operationKind": "query",
    "text": "query ClientsAtomsQuery {\n  clients {\n    Id\n    age\n    gender\n    income\n    location\n  }\n}\n"
  }
};
})();

(node as any).hash = "e029635c746ef9ec4ca4b7503898730d";

export default node;
```

Comment: can u please share us the error log?

Answer (score 0):

I've got same error yours.

I fixed my code as follow below.

It works well.

```html
const clientsSelector = graphQLSelector({
  key: "clientsSelector",
  environment: RelayEnvironment,
  query: graphql`
    query ClientsAtomsQuery {
      clients {
        Id
        age
        gender
        income
        location
      }
    }
  `.default,
  variables: {},
  mapResponse: (data) => data.clients as Array<Client>,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil/issues/1998) (which may end up working for you, it didn't for me).

You have to set the relay compiler option for eagerEsModules to true:

```json
{
  "eagerEsModules": true`
}
```

See [the relay docs](https://relay.dev/docs/getting-started/installation-and-setup/#compiler-configuration) for more info about where to set this option. At present day the option is set in either the `relay.config.js` file like so:

**relay.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  // misc default config you can change
  src: "./src",
  language: "typescript",
  schema: "./data/schema.graphql",
  exclude: ["**/node_modules/**", "**/__mocks__/**", "**/__generated__/**"],
  eagerEsModules: true // <------- The line you should add
}
```

You may also have the relay options set in the package.json which you could then set like so:

**package.json**

```json
{
  "relay": {
    "src": "./src",
    "language": "typescript",
    "schema": "./data/schema.graphql",
    "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "**/__mocks__/**", "**/__generated__/**"],
    "eagerEsModules": true
  }
}
```

Though those would likely be the most common places you would change it. For me, I didn't change it in either of those places though, because I was using webpack, swc, and @swc/plugin-relay, so I had to go change it in my  `.swcrc.js` file. Others may have trouble with webpack and may have to change it in their webpack configs.